# How to Pass Java List of Objects to Oracle Stored Procedure Using MyBatis?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, mybatis

I have been googling this for a while and cannot seem to find any real answers.

I have an Oracle stored procedure that has a number of in parameters that have a type that is table of the table rowtype.  So for example:

**Declared in the pacakge:**

```
TYPE param1_type_t IS TABLE OF table1%ROWTYPE;
TYPE param2_type_t IS TABLE OF table2%ROWTYPE;
TYPE param3_type_t IS TABLE OF table3%ROWTYPE;
```

**Oracle Procedure:**

```
PROCEDURE my_proc
(
   parameter1    IN param1_type_t,
   parameter2    IN param2_type_t,
   parameter3    IN param3_type_t
)
```

On the java side, I have 3 corresponding Lists of objects representing each of the parameters that are populated in Java.  Is it possible to call the Oracle procedure using MyBatis in this scenario?

```
<update id="callOracleSP" statementType="CALLABLE">
    {CALL my_proc( #{param1, mode=IN},
                   #{param2, mode=IN},
                   #{param3, mode=IN}
                 )
    }
</update>
```

The objects themselves are simple VOs with String and Integer properties and their respective getters and setters.

I am not really sure how to proceed.  Do I need to somehow map the Java object lists to the Oracle types?

Answer (score 12):

I can't tell if you do already or not,  but you'll need Oracle objects defined.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SCHEMA."YOUR_OBJECT" AS OBJECT
(
    field_one    varchar2(50),
    field_two    varchar2(100)
);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SCHEMA."YOUR_OBJECT_ARRAY" AS TABLE OF YOUR_OBJECT;
/
```

Then you can write type handlers to map the Java objects to the Oracle objects.

```
import oracle.sql.ARRAY;
import oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor;
import oracle.sql.STRUCT;
import oracle.sql.StructDescriptor;
....
public class YourTypeHandler implements TypeHandler
{
....
    public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, Object parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException
    {
        List<YourObject> objects = (List<YourObject>) parameter;

        StructDescriptor structDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("YOUR_OBJECT", ps.getConnection());

        STRUCT[] structs = new STRUCT[objects.size()];
        for (int index = 0; index < objects.size(); index++)
        {
            YourObject pack = packs.get(index);
            Object[] params = new Object[2];
            params[0] = pack.getFieldOne();
            params[1] = pack.getFieldTwo();
            STRUCT struct = new STRUCT(structDescriptor, ps.getConnection(), params);
            structs[index] = struct;
        }

        ArrayDescriptor desc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("YOUR_OBJECT_ARRAY", ps.getConnection());
        ARRAY oracleArray = new ARRAY(desc, ps.getConnection(), structs);
        ps.setArray(i, oracleArray);
    }
}
```

Then invoke the procedure,

```
call your_proc
(
#{yourObjects, javaType=Object, jdbcType=ARRAY, jdbcTypeName=YOUR_OBJECT_ARRAY, mode=IN, typeHandler=YourObjectArrayTypeHandler}
)
```

Comment: can't find class/jar for TypeHandler. already have ojdbc6.jar

Comment: brother what if  pack.getFieldOne() is another TAB (array)

Answer (score 1):

Andy Pryor's answer is very good I tested it and it really works. But it has an error at typeHandler:

```
call your_proc
(
#{yourObjects, javaType=Object, jdbcType=ARRAY, jdbcTypeName=YOUR_OBJECT_ARRAY, mode=IN, typeHandler=YourObjectArrayTypeHandler}
)
```

should be:

```
call your_proc
(
#{yourObjects, javaType=Object, jdbcType=ARRAY, jdbcTypeName=YOUR_OBJECT_ARRAY, mode=IN, typeHandler=YourTypeHandler}
)
```

The TypeHandler has an error as well: (there is no "packs" and there is some difference in the method parameters in my version)

```
@Override
public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, Object parameter, String arg3) throws SQLException {
    List<YourObject> objects = (List<YourObject>) parameter;

    StructDescriptor structDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("YOUR_OBJECT", ps.getConnection());

    STRUCT[] structs = new STRUCT[objects.size()];
    for (int index = 0; index < objects.size(); index++)
    {
        YourObject pack = objects.get(index);
        Object[] params = new Object[2];
        params[0] = pack.getFieldOne();
        params[1] = pack.getFieldTwo();
        STRUCT struct = new STRUCT(structDescriptor, ps.getConnection(), params);
        structs[index] = struct;
    }

    ArrayDescriptor desc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("YOUR_OBJECT_ARRAY", ps.getConnection());
    ARRAY oracleArray = new ARRAY(desc, ps.getConnection(), structs);
    ps.setArray(i, oracleArray);
}
```

And here is an example for xml mapping:

```
  <parameterMap id="updateHierPersonAssignMap" class="java.util.Map" >                      
    <parameter property="p_array" jdbcType="ARRAY" javaType="Object" mode="IN" typeHandler="com.aamtech.ria.model.domain.typehandler.YourTypeHandler"/>
  </parameterMap>
  <procedure id="updateHierPersonAssign" parameterMap="updateHierPersonAssignMap" >
    <![CDATA[ 
        { call ria_am_util_pkg.j_update_hier_person_assign( ? ) }
    ]]>
  </procedure>
```

And here is how you can call it from the DAO:

```
public void update(List array) {
    Map<String, Object> queryParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    queryParams.put("p_array", array);
    try {
        client.update("HashMapResult.updateHierPersonAssign", queryParams);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    }
}
```

And my procedure looks like this (it just inserts a row into a test table):

```
Procedure j_update_hier_person_assign (p_array IN YOUR_OBJECT_ARRAY) is
  begin
     FOR i IN 1..p_array.count LOOP
       --dbms_output.put_line();
       insert into test (a) values (p_array(i).field_one);
     END LOOP;
  end;
```

Comment: params[0] = pack.getFieldOne(); what if this is another Array(Tab of Tab)