# Spring Mybatis - sending array as input parameter to procedure call in mapper.xml

Tags: spring, mybatis

I'm using the following code for passing java array to stored procedure

```
<select id="abcd" parameterType="java.util.Map" statementType="CALLABLE">
    {call PKG_xyz.PR_cbcd(
        #{p_array,jdbcType=ARRAY,typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.ArrayTypeHandler,mode=IN},
        #{p_ids,jdbcType=INTEGER,mode=IN},
        #{p_comments,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN},
        #{p_return_code,jdbcType=INTEGER,mode=OUT},
        #{p_msg_out,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=OUT}   
    )}
</select>
```

here, p_array is my java array. But i'm getting the following error -->
"**Error setting null for parameter #1 with JdbcType ARRAY . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different jdbcTypeForNull configuration property. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: sqlType=2003**"

Could somebody please help....

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Try to write your custom TypeHandler like

```
public class ArrayTypeHandler implements TypeHandler<YourArrayObject[]>{
}
```

Override this method below to set oracle.sql.ARRAY to PreparedStatement:-

```
public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i,
            YourArrayObject[] parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {}
```

This url might help you do the same:-
[How to Pass Java List of Objects to Oracle Stored Procedure Using MyBatis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719689/how-to-pass-java-list-of-objects-to-oracle-stored-procedure-using-mybatis)

Similarly, override getResult() method to get OUT array paramter