# Looping in insert query in mybatis

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I have one pojo class like this:

```
public class Pojo {
    String a;
    String b;
    String c;
    List<Integer>  d;
    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    public String getC() {
        return c;
    }
    public void setC(String c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
    public List<Integer> getD() {
        return d;
    }
    public void setD(List<Integer> d) {
        this.d = d;
    }
```

---

```
<insert id="insertPojoval" parameterType="com.Pojo">
insert into abc values(#{a},#{b},#{c},#{d},)
</insert>
```

How can I insert this pojo values in one insert query using mybatis?

I want that for each values in the list `List<Integer>  d` values of `a`, `b`, and `c` should be inserted. How can I loop for each value in `List<Integer>  d`?

I am getting problem in looping for each value in list `d`.

Comment: You might want to tag Java and mybatis so people from those communities can chip in.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look into Oracle Objects and mybatis `TypeHandler`. Have a look at this: [How to Pass Java List of Objects to Oracle Stored Procedure Using MyBatis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719689/how-to-pass-java-list-of-objects-to-oracle-stored-procedure-using-mybatis)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mybatis "foreach" tag to insert as to collection. But I'm not sure this is what you want or not. Refer to below answer and hope it help.

```
<insert id="insertPojoval" parameterType="com.Pojo">
        INSERT INTO 
            abc
        VALUES
            <foreach collection="list" item="d" index="index" open="(" separator="),("  close=")">
                #{a},
                #{b},
                #{c},
                #{d}
            </foreach>      
</insert>
```